# How to attach a tag template to a dataset in GCP using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, tags, dataset, google-data-catalog

I have generated tag templates with Terraform, intending to associate them with various datasets in GCP. Despite my efforts to identify a connection between the datasets and the tag templates, I was unable to find any.

Note: here's the used module https://github.com/drandell/terraform-google-datacatalog/blob/v1.0.0/modules/tag-template/main.tf